# What are coquantales?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, coalgebras

A [quantale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantale) can be defined as a monoid in the monoidal category $\mathbf{Sup}$ of complete join semilattices, equipped with tensor product.

What are examples of non-diagonal comonoids in $\mathbf{Sup}$?

Comment: For instance, any localic group has an underlying Hopf algebra.

Comment: @ZhenLin : I do not quite understand. I see that a localic group is a monoid in $(\mathbf{Loc},\times)$ and this is the same thing as a comonoid in $(\mathbf{Frm},\oplus)$. How do we get a comonoid in $(\mathbf{Sup},\otimes)$ from that? Is the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Frm}\to\mathbf{Sup}$ lax comonoidal?

Comment: A frame is a monoid in $\mathbf{Sup}$, and the coproduct in $\mathbf{Frm}$ is the tensor product in $\mathbf{Sup}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: I get it. Just like abelian groups and commutative rings. Thanks.